# Shift slows me down instead of running

Tags: fallout-new-vegas

When I press <kbd>Left Shift</kbd>, my character walks slower, instead of running. <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd> is turned off. When I turn <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd> on, he always walks slowly instead of running.

I only played 1 hour, killing creatures around wells. I don't think I carry a lot of weight.

Any solution please?

Please watch this video to see the "shift effect":

Comment: Check the keybinding? First thing that pops to mind.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You have the Always Run function toggled on; what you're seeing when you hold shift is walking speed; the game makes the Run key function as a Walk key when Always Run is on.

You may think that Always Run is off, because you said that Caps Lock is off, and Caps Lock is the default key for Always Run. Except, the game isn't looking at your actual Caps Lock state, it instead just looks at presses of the Caps Lock key as a toggle to switch between them. If you exit to the main menu (or open the Steam overlay), press Caps Lock to toggle it, and re-enter the game, your Always Run state won't have changed, and things will probably line up the way you expect them to.